# How to expand a trigonometric function, consisting 'sin' and 'cos' of any power to 'sin' and 'cos' terms in power of one in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplification

We have the following expression:

if:

> v(t)=Vrf.sin(Wrf.t)+Vlo.sin(Wlo.t);

then:

> v^2(t)=(Vrf.sin(Wrf.t)+Vlo.sin(Wlo.t))^2

which is then simplified to:

> v^2(t)=Vrf^2.(1+cos(2.Wrf.t))+Vlo^2.(1+cos(2.Wlo.t))+2.Vrf.Vlo.(cos((Wrf-Wlo).t)+cos((Wrf+Wlo).t));

The purpose of this kind of simplification is to have 'sin' and 'cos' terms of power of one from a trigonometric function, consisting 'sin' and 'cos' of any power.

The question is that how can I perform the simplification of higher order of v(t) ( v(t)^n ) into terms of 'sin' and 'cos' of power of one in Matlab?

edition added:
Looking for specific simplification codes in symbolic Matlab!

Comment: Check out the formulas [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula). Just program them into your matlab file.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I am looking for a kind of simplification in Matlab for symbolic representations!

Comment: So you want to use the symbolic toolbox and results should still be symbolic functions? Will your input be always a 2-tone signal (i.e. with two frequencies) or are more tones possible?

Comment: Yes, I want to use symbolic Matlab, and it should be considered that v(t) is equal to a.sin(w1.t)+b.sin(w2.t)+c.sin(w3.t)+... in general, and I am looking for the simplification of v(t) in any power ( v(t)^n )